# How would a temperature profile in wall change if the rate of heat transfer increases

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, thermal-conductivity

> Given the system below, how would the temperature profile in the wall change if the heat transfer in Fluid II was very fast?
>
> [image]

If the heat transfer in Fluid II is very fast, then the T-profile for $\ce{T_{2∞}}$ would experience less resistance and hence have a more linear slope. However, I don't understand how this would affect the T-profile inside the wall? Wouldn't Fluid II have the same temperature and interact with the interface at the same point, meaning nothing changes within the wall?

Comment: Do you mean ‘wall is good thermal conductor’?

Answer (score 3):

If the heat transfer in fluid 2 is fast, the thickness of the boundary layer wall - fluid 2 is very small (the 'not so linear' part of the temperature profile on that side)

One can then approximate that the temperature of fluid 2 directly at the wall is equivalent to the bulk temperature.

So the temperature profile through the wall would be steeper, indicating a larger overall heatflux - see it as a self fullfilling prophecy: fast heat transfer will allow you to transfer heat faster